# FileNotFoundException for site with tilde when using httpurlconnection

Tags: android, post, character-encoding, httpurlconnection

There is a strange problem when trying post some data to site with tilde.
How could I fix that in Android?

For example, this is my site:
`http://host-site.com/~username/form.php`

Here is my code for that:

```
url = new URL(hostSiteString);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "myHost");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
bos.write(readyToken.getBytes(), 0, readyToken.length());
bos.flush();
bos.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, I had to decode my url.

```
String decode = URLDecoder.decode(hostSiteString);
url = new URL(decode);
```

Comment: That is strange. I would have supposed that you had to url Encode your url.